# Identify soft lego wings

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I wonder in which set the following piece appears (the soft plastic wing).
It is most likely in year 2012-2016.

[image: wing]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be [76039-1: Ant-Man Final Battle](https://brickset.com/sets/76039-1/Ant-Man-Final-Battle) from 2015.

[image]

The blue and yellow-green marbled parts don't go to the set though, they are from one of [3 Ninjago sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=18396pb02&in=S) that are also from 2015.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the answer!